# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx, appcompatactivity

Just create empty project and inherit my activity from `AppCompatActivity()`
cause error in LogCat each time app running.

> androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

When I change `AppCompatActivity()` to regular `Activity()` everething works fine without warning pointed above.

**P.S** Please, don`t write that it is just warning, I know. Bul also want to know how to fix or hide it.

Comment: What makes you think that there is something wrong? These sorts of warnings show up from time to time, due to some of the sophisticated stuff going on (e.g., multidex, Instant Run).

Comment: Seems like you`re right. Thank you.